# How can i change the order of 2 objects in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So, I have a size 3 bucket array. Declared as:

```
Bucket* bucket = new Bucket[size]();
```

And I have a function that prints out the address of the each bucket:

```
printBucket(Bucket* tempBucket)
{
cout << "Address is:" << tempbucket << endl;
}
```

Lets say it outputs(for all buckets):

```
1st bucket address:015650DC
2nd bucket address:015650E8
3rd bucket address:015650F4
```

I would like to change the second bucket with the third so i created this function:

```
Bucket* changeBucket(Bucket* buckets, int first, int second)
{

    Bucket* temp = new Bucket();
    temp = &buckets[first];
    buckets[first] = buckets[second];
    buckets[second] = *temp;
    return buckets;
}
```

After i call this function address outputs are still the same:

```
1st bucket address:015650DC
2nd bucket address:015650E8
3rd bucket address:015650F4
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
1st bucket address:015650DC
2nd bucket address:015650F4
3rd bucket address:015650E8
```

Comment: You leak memory in `changeBucket` in just the first two lines. This isn't Java; you don't have to `new` everything. You also lose the real first value of your array, and duplicate the second.

Comment: Is [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: "_I  have a size 3 bucket array. Declared as have a size 3 bucket array. Declared as..._" - why? Why isn't it a `std::vector<Bucker> buckets(size)`?

Comment: Also, with the point @WhozCraig raised in mind, what does the `Bucket` copy constructor/assignment operator look like?

Comment: Your desired output is inconsistent with what an array is. An array arranges its contents sequentially in memory. If it has three objects, the address of the second is between that of the first and third. Always. That's how an array works. So you've jumped into an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Is your real goal checking the success of your `changeBucket` function? If so, you should look at the *contents* of the array's elements, not the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
Bucket* changeBucket(Bucket* buckets, int first, int second)
{

Bucket temp;
temp = buckets[first];
buckets[first] = buckets[second];
buckets[second] = temp;
return buckets;
}
```

And you can also change the prototype to "void", the changes you make in the array are permanent (arrays are pointers in the end)

Comment: You could go even simpler by combining the first two lines: `Bucket temp = buckets[first];`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are swapping the ***contents*** of two array elements but you are not (and cannot) change the addresses of the array elements.

When you create the array with `Bucket* bucket = new Bucket[size]();` you are creating a block of memory large enough to hold `size` objects of type `Bucket`. This will be a **contiguous** block of memory, where any element can be accessed using the `[]` operator, such that `bucket[2]` will refer to the third (indexes start at zero) element.

So, when you call your `changeBucket` function, you are changing the contents of two elements of the array. You **are not** changing the addresses of those elements, which will always be fixed relative to the first element (which is itself determined by the `new[]` operation).

*If you could change the addresses, it would then invalidate the whole concept of an array, because, what you seem to want is that an expression like `bucket[2]` should then refer to the second element, rather than the third - and this is clearly unacceptable to the basic tenets of `c++` programming.*

Alternatively, what you may be looking for, is an **array of pointers to buckets** - in which each element of the array points to an object; in this case, you could then (legally) swap those pointers. I can provide some code changes, if this is what you are looking to do.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.